How to add another progress step of CART before the Shipping progress bar in magento 2

Hi, In magento 2 how can we add another progress bar on checkout page. By default there are 2 "Shipping" , "Review & Payments". I want to add another which will be like "Cart".
When customer clicks on that it will show the cart page details to that
What is the best practice to achieve it ? Do we need to registerStep ?

Here is the working solution
create file app/code/Aam/Payment/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
and add code below
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- New Cart Details Step -->
                                        <item name="cart-details-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Aam_Payment/js/view/checkout-cart-step</item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item> <!-- Display before shipping -->
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <!-- Add child components if needed -->
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

2nd step create file
app/code/Aam/Payment/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout-cart-step.js
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache'
    ],
    function (ko, Component, stepNavigator, customer, quote, cartCache) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Aam_Payment/checkout-cart-details'
            },

            isVisible: ko.observable(true), // Control visibility
            stepCode: 'cartdetails',
            stepTitle: "Cart Details",

            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                // Register your step
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    this.stepCode,
                    null,
                    this.stepTitle,
                    this.isVisible,
                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                    0 // Sort order to appear before other steps
                );
                return this;
            },

            /**
             * The navigate() method can be customized for conditions before switching to this step.
             */
            navigate: function () {
                // Custom navigation logic, if any
            },

            /**
             * Get cart items
             * Use quote.getItems() to fetch items in the cart for display
             */
            cartItems: ko.observableArray(quote.getItems()),

            /**
             * Get totals for display in the cart step
             */
            cartTotals: ko.computed(function() {
                return quote.totals();
            }),

            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);

3rd and last step
app/code/Aam/Payment/view/frontend/web/template/checkout-cart-details.html
<!-- Use 'stepCode' as id attribute -->
<li data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible, attr: { id: stepCode }">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: stepTitle" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title" class="step-content cart-details-step-content" data-role="content">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <h3 data-bind="i18n: 'Cart Summary'"></h3>
            <ul class="cart-items-list" data-bind="foreach: cartItems">
                <li class="cart-item">
                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                    <span data-bind="text: qty"></span>
                    <span data-bind="text: price"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="cart-totals">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Subtotal:'"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: cartTotals().subtotal"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="action-next-step" data-bind="click: navigateToNextStep, i18n: 'Next'">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>

Do remember to change Aam_Payment with your vendor module name.
Result will be


thank you for the quick response. Can we render the entire cart page to the Cart Defails tab? I want to make my checkout in three steps. The current answer is good. But need to have a work like that.. OR You can say if customer clicks on cart details it should go on cart page, the progres bar should  then show on a cart page as well in that case.
